# How can I get the estimate of lmFit function form limma package

Tags: phylogenetics, limma, methylation

This is the first time that I used `lmfit` function from the [limma](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) package

- I'm a little bit confused on how to interpret the result.
- is there a way to get the estimate or the beta parameter of `lmfit`

Comment: Normally you run the results through eBayes() and get the coefficients from that.